# Order of dependency injection when using scopes

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm currently trying to figure out Dagger 2. I am trying to set up 4 scopes: App, User, Activity, Fragment. User and Activity components are Subcomponents of App. Fragment is a Component with Activity as its dependency.

Say my UserSettingsActivity needs a Toolbar (provided by ActivityModule), and a UserProfile (provided by UserModule). I won't get a UserProfile until I ask for it from the database, whereas the Toolbar can be provided right away. So the order of injection that takes place is into ActivityComponent first, then into UserComponent. I have 2 @Inject fields, one for Toolbar and one for UserProfile in the activity. I was hoping that dagger will know that the dependencies are coming from different modules, but it seems to complain that UserProfile can't be provided when injected into ActivityComponent. Obviously it can't be provided by ActivityModule, but why is it not making a connection that UserProfile is provided by UserModule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my best knowledge, Dagger-2 doesn't support "partial injections".

Therefore, when you call `myComponent.inject(this)`, Dagger-2 throws an error if `myComponent` can't provide all `@Inject` annotated members of `this`.

I see two ways to work around this limitation:

1. Remove `@Inject` annotation from `UserProfile`, expose `UserProfile` via public method in `UserComponent` and inject it manually when `UserComponent` is ready to be used. Something analogous to this: `userProfile = userComponent.getUserProfile()`
2. Don't make `UserComponent` dependent on data fetching. `UserComponent` could be used to inject `Toolbar` and some `UserProfileProvider` at the same time, and you will fetch `UserProfile` from `UserProfileProvider` when it is available.

I personally think that second approach is the better choice. DI libraries should be used in order to satisfy objects' dependencies at construction time. In Android we can't construct `Activity` or `Fragment` ourselves, therefore we perform DI in `onCreate()`, `onAttach()`, `onCreateView()`, etc., but it does not mean that we should be using DI libraries in order to assist in controlling the flow of applications.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this similar question. I'm stuck :|

Answer (score 2):

Subcomponents work's similar to inheritance(extends), in your case User component and Activity component extending App component but there is no relation between User component and Activity component so when you request User dependency in Activity it will fail.

Subcomponent can't provide any dependency to other Subcomponent.

Instead, you can make Activity component as a subcomponent of User component. This will also give you the flexibility to switch user.

Comment: Please have a look at this question. I'm stuck https://stackoverflow.com/q/45189295/5214893