# Dagger 2 How to inject one class to multiple components using Sub components?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Can any please provide example code to achieve this scenario using sub components. **In MyActivity i need to fulfill dependencies from multiple components.** As you can see in below code MyActivity requies injection from `compA via module classA` and `compB via module classB`.

```
@Component(modules = classA.class)
interface compA
{
void inject(MyActivity target);
}

@Component(modules = classB.class)
interface compB
{
void inject(MyActivity target);
}
```

I have been trying many different things for quite some time. I have also read official docs regarding sub components but unable to understand how to do for my scenario. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this stuff. include modules is one of that. we have to modules AndroidModules and NetworkModules.

```
@Module(includes = AndroidModules.class)
public class NetworkModules {
//Here two module are marge ....
}
```

Now in My component

```
@Component(modules = NetworkModules.class)
public interface NetworkComponent {
    void inject(MyActivity activity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way if i want to make my components or modules independent?

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this,

```
@Component(
    modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class,
        MainModule.class
    }
)
public interface compA
{
void inject(MyActivity target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Previously i tried this, but the problem with this approach is that it create tight coupling. I want to make my components independent.